# MvcMusicStore Deployment Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy the MvcMusicStore on my website, but I'm running into some issues with the page navigation at the top.  I'm getting a 404 not found error on these links.  I think this is a routing issue, but it works locally.  The odd thing is the genre links also work on the page.  I've included the link to my deployment site as well as the routing code.

http://mybeatonpath.com/MvcMusicStore"

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
            );

    }
```

Comment: Which version of IIS do you have on server that doesn't work?

Comment: It seems that all of your top nav links work when there is a trailing / on the end.

Comment: Yes.  I also tried adding the /Index on the end.  The code for creating these links is below:

Comment: <li>@Html.ActionLink("Store", "Index", "Store")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Store", "Index", "Store")</li>
            <li>@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");}</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "StoreManager")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "StoreManager")</li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to enable ASP.NET 4.0 on IIS.

Here's how this coud be done in IIS 6.0:

[image]

Also you need a [wildcard mapping](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-asp-net-mvc-under-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-classic-mode---solution-to-routing-problem) in order to use extensionless urls for IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 (Classic mode). In IIS 7.0 Integrated mode you don't need to configure this mapping.

Comment: ASP.NET 4.0 is enabled on IIS and this site is using ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: Adding the wildcard mapping did help, but the Admin link is still not working.

Comment: The Admin link not working was unrelated to this issue.  The wildcard mapping fixed my issue.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have IIS6 running. You need to make some adjustments so that IIS knows how to handle MVC routing. You need to set up IIS6 Extension-less URLs.

[Here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) is an explanation on how to proceed.

Comment: It looks like IIS7 is running.